# Raspbian Jessie Lite apt-get problem

Tags: raspbian, apt, jessie-lite, dpkg

every apt-get install operation runs in to the following error

dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

it is an fresh install (2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite)

can some one help me

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update first? Have you cleared the apt cache and redownloaded the packages?

Comment: yes have run apt-get uptate first then i have tried to delete /var/cache/apt and run apt-get update again but no effect

Answer (score 2):

Mount the orginal image file

```
sudo mount ./2016-09-23-raspbian-jessie-lite.img ../rasp/root -o offset=$((137216*512))
```

Copy /var/lib/dpkg again to the sdcard of the pi and everything worked.